# How do I add prices to items in a combo box?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I need to create a simple GUI app using Swing in Eclipse. I've decided that I wanted to make a simple Car Rental service app.

I'm not too sure on how to attach prices to the car models and days that are in two separate combo boxes. I'm also not too sure on how to make the combined price of the car model and day appear in a text box once a hire button is pressed.

Below is a picture of my GUI just so you guys can see what I'm working with. I've also added my code that I have so far.

[Picture of my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEV2M.jpg)

```
private JLabel l0 = new JLabel("  Car  Rental  ");
    private JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Name ");
    private JTextField t1=new JTextField(" ",8);
    private JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Email ");
    private JTextField t2=new JTextField(" ",8);
    private JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Phone Number ");
    private JTextField t3=new JTextField("0",8);
    private JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Car Model ");
    private String [] models={"BMW","Mercedes","Audi"};
    private JComboBox c1=new JComboBox(models);
    private JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Days ");
    private String [] days={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
    private JComboBox c2=new JComboBox(days);
    private JButton b1=new JButton("Hire");
    private JTextField t4=new JTextField("0",8);
    private JButton b2=new JButton("Print Receipt"); 
    private JButton b3=new JButton("Exit");
    private JPanel p1=new JPanel();

    public MyFrame2(String s){
        super(s);
        Container content=getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Font f=new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD,20);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));
        l0.setFont(f);  l1.setFont(f);

        content.add(l0);

        p1.add(l1); p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(l2); p1.add(t2);
        p1.add(l3); p1.add(t3);
        p1.add(l4); p1.add(c1);
        p1.add(l5); p1.add(c2);
        p1.add(b1); p1.add(t4);
        p1.add(b2); p1.add(b3);


        content.add(p1);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        setSize(270,320);    setVisible(true);}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        Object target=e.getSource();

        if (target==b1)

        if (target==b2){
            System.out.println("====Receipt====");
            System.out.println("Name: " + t1.getText());
            System.out.println("Phone Number: " + t3.getText());
            System.out.println("Car Model: " + c1.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("Days: " + c2.getSelectedItem());}

        if (target==b3) {
            System.exit(1);}


                 }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest using `GridBagLayout` rather than `FormLayout`. Refer to Oracle's java tutorials, specifically the lesson entitled [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The below code should get you started. It is incomplete since I didn't find all the requirements in your question.

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class CarsHire implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JButton hireButton;
    private JButton receiptButton;
    private JComboBox<Car> carModelsCombo;
    private JComboBox<Integer> daysCombo;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField emailTextField;
    private JTextField nameTextField;
    private JTextField phoneTextField;
    private JTextField priceTextField;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object src = event.getSource();
        if (exitButton == src) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (hireButton == src) {
            displayPrice();
        }
        else if (receiptButton == src) {
            System.out.println("====Receipt====");
            System.out.println("Name: " + t1.getText());
            System.out.println("Phone Number: " + t3.getText());
            System.out.println("Car Model: " + c1.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("Days: " + c2.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createHeaderPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        receiptButton = new JButton("Print Receipt");
        receiptButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        receiptButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(receiptButton);

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(exitButton);

        exitButton.setPreferredSize(receiptButton.getPreferredSize());

        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createHeaderPanel() {
        JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Car Rental");
        Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20);
        headerLabel.setFont(f);
        headerPanel.add(headerLabel);
        return headerPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        // First row of form.
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        nameLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        mainPanel.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        nameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        mainPanel.add(nameTextField, gbc);
        nameLabel.setLabelFor(nameTextField);

        // Second row of form.
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email");
        emailLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        mainPanel.add(emailLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        emailTextField = new JTextField(10);
        mainPanel.add(emailTextField, gbc);
        emailLabel.setLabelFor(emailTextField);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JLabel phoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone Number");
        phoneLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        mainPanel.add(phoneLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        phoneTextField = new JTextField(10);
        mainPanel.add(phoneTextField, gbc);
        phoneLabel.setLabelFor(phoneTextField);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        JLabel carModelLabel = new JLabel("Car Model");
        carModelLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        mainPanel.add(carModelLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        Car[] carModels = new Car[]{new Car("BMW", new BigDecimal(36295)),
                                    new Car("Mercedes", new BigDecimal(33795)),
                                    new Car("Audi", new BigDecimal(34295))};
        carModelsCombo = new JComboBox<>(carModels);
        carModelsCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        mainPanel.add(carModelsCombo, gbc);
        carModelLabel.setLabelFor(carModelsCombo);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        JLabel daysLabel = new JLabel("Days");
        daysLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        mainPanel.add(daysLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        daysCombo = new JComboBox<>(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
        daysCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        mainPanel.add(daysCombo, gbc);
        daysLabel.setLabelFor(daysCombo);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        hireButton = new JButton("Hire");
        hireButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        hireButton.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(hireButton, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        priceTextField = new JTextField(10);
        mainPanel.add(priceTextField, gbc);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void displayPrice() {
        Car car = (Car) carModelsCombo.getSelectedItem();
        if (car != null) {
            BigDecimal price = car.getPrice();
            priceTextField.setText(price.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new CarsHire());
    }
}

class Car {
    private String model;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public Car(String model, BigDecimal price) {
        this.model = model;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

*Swing* code is executed on the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). The `JFrame` constructor will launch the EDT but there was a time where Oracle recommended explicitly launching the EDT via method `invokeLater()` of class `EventQueue`. That method takes a single argument which is an instance of a class that implements the `Runnable` interface.

*Swing* uses the *Model-View-Controller* (MVC) paradigm so each *Swing* component has a *model* that stores the data that the component displays. `JComboBox` model is its list of items. That list can contain objects of any class. The value displayed by the `JComboBox` is the value returned by the `toString()` method of the class. Hence I created a `Car` class that contains the car's model and its price. Hence what is displayed in the `JComboBox` is just the [car] model, but the selected item is actually an instance of class `Car`. So in the `displayPrice()` method, I know that the value returned by `getSelectedItem()` must be an instance of `Car` (or null if nothing is selected). From there it's simple to obtain the [car] price and display it in the `priceTextField`.

Initially, I thought the price meant the actual price of the car, that's why I used `BigDecimal` for the *price* in class `Car`.

As I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803830/how-do-i-add-prices-to-items-in-a-combo-box#comment107577816_60803830) to your question, I use `GridBagLayout` since it is very suitable for laying out forms. There are other layout managers that are also suitable for laying out forms. I am just used to using `GridBagLayout`.

I also use mnemonics. For example if you press the keys Alt+H it will activate the *Hire* button and if you press Alt+N, the *Name* text field will become the focused field.

Refer to [Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) which is part of Oracle's java tutorials. The default *content pane* for a `JFrame` is a `JPanel` whose layout manager is `BorderLayout`. When you program in *Swing* you need to look at the source code a lot to understand what's going on and how best to utilize the framework.